# Im trying to extract selected columns using col=[] and then use a function where Company Name == Egypt && dialcode==20

Tags: python

Im trying to extract selected columns using col=[] and then use a function to get values where Company Name == Egypt && dialcode==20

i used the below syntax:

`your text`'import pandas as pd
`your text`'import numpy as np
`your text`file="---"
`your text`data=pd.read_excel(file)
`your text`df=pd.DataFrame(data)
`your text`cols=       [0,1,2,3,4,5]
`your text`data= pd.read_excel(file,usecols=cols)
`your text`data=pd.DataFrame(data)
`your text`df_Egypt=data.loc[(data.CompName=='Egypt', data.DialCode=='20')]
`your text`print(df_Egypt)'

Error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'DialCode'

Comment: Please post your code with proper formatting.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/3890632)

Comment: Maybe you meant dialcode  instead of DialCode?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you show the input file contents?